# Matplotlib reports font family 'serif' not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

When I try and run, for example:

```
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15,7]
plt.plot(data['flow-time'], data['staticpressurerecovery'])
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Static Pressure Recovery [-]')
plt.title('McD13_4S3 Plenum: Performance Coefficient ')
plt.ylim((0.33, 0.4))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

in a Jupyter notebook, I get the following error message:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py:1331: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

#### Things I've Tried:

1. Deleting the `fontList.cache`, `fontList.json`, and `fontList.py3.cache`
2. Uncommenting the font family related sections of the `matplotlibrc` file
3. Uninstalled and reinstalled `matplotlib` using `pip uninstall matplotlib` and `pip install matplotlib`

Nothing has solved the issue. The only possible way for me to get different fonts now is to use LaTeX as the backend, but that's slow and unnecessary.

Any ideas what I can try next?

Edit: I'm using Windows 10, so not using `apt-get` for me. That seems to be a common fix for these problems, but I can't do it. It appears those solutions just add Microsoft fonts to the Linux font manager, so it's probably not even relevant since I'm already on a Microsoft machine.

Minimum working Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
mpl.rcParams['font.serif'] = 'Computer Modern'


t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()
```

In `fontList.json`, Computer Modern is listed as an available font.

Comment: That's sure a strange error because it should of course work (and does for me). I assume you did restart the kernel in between, right? So the first thing in such cases is always to produce a [mcve]. In this case this would be 3 or 4 lines long and would be the only thing in your notebook. If this reproduces the error you can at least be sure that you did not do something strange in the remainder of the code.

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've updated the question with a working example. Problem has slightly changed now, but I still can't figure out why it's not working right.

Comment: I think computer modern is a valid font set for `mathtext.fontset`, but at least my windows computer does not have computer modern as ttf font installed. Something like `mpl.rcParams['font.serif'] = 'Times New Roman'` should however work on any windows computer.

Comment: I've added the 'Computer Modern' ttf to the data directory for matplotlib and those files are showing up in the `fontsList.json` file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, changing my matplotlib version from back to `1.5.3` solves the issue. You need to `pip uninstall matplotlib` first then `pip install matplotlib==1.5.3`.

More context, I was using `ggplot` on zeppelin notebook with Amazon EC2. Somehow the matplotlib version installed was `2.2.3`.

After changing the version, the error is gone